# Preview image from pipe

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, preview, x11

I have a command line utility, let's called as: `produce_image`. So i can do the following in the Terminal:

```
$ produce_image > some.jpg
$ open some.jpg #opens Preview.app
```

also, I have `ImageMagick` installed and `Xqartz` too, so I can do the following:

```
$ produce_image | display #the display is a command from ImageMagick suite
```

The above opens an X11 window with the image.

Is possible achieve such image-view as with `display` also with `Preview.app`? e.g. looking for something like:

```
$ produce_image | Preview.app #of course, this isn't working
$ produce_image | /Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview #nor this
```

Is possible preview the image with `Preview.app` **without** using intermediate file?

Ps: of course, I can create a command such `osxdisplay`

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/foobar.XXXXXX)
cat - > "$tmpfile"
open "$tmpfile"
rm -f $tmpfile
```

and use it as

```
produce_image | osxdisplay
```

But the merit of the question is about opening images from a shell pipe without intermediate files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
produce_image | open -a Preview.app -f
```

(To be honest, I was quite surprised to learn that this works)

Comment: GREAT! Working! THANX! :) (Where is this documented?)

Comment: I had a look at `man open` and then went to see whether `-f` also works for non-text documents. Tara!

Comment: I'm simply blind! :( Somewhat missed the _ *-f**  Reads input from standard input and opens the results in the default text editor_ part. Thank again, you're THE Great!

Comment: is there any way to do the same trick for HTML stream?

Comment: @ab If you have a different question, feel free to ask it using the Ask Question button at the top right. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. Also, please explain what you mean by "HTML stream".

Comment: thanks for tips @patrix. By HTML stream I mean exactly the same situation as described in this answer, but instead of binary stream with image content the text stream piped to the Preview app like  `cat index.html | open -a Preview.app -f` I wrote `cat index.html` to illustrate. In my particular case this is a stream html output from markdown processor

Answer (score 2):

This displays image data from STDIN in the terminal in iTerm 2 (https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-images.html):

```
cat file.png|printf "\e]1337;File=inline=1:$(base64)\a\n"
```

The function below displays one or more images in the terminal.

```
ima(){ local f;for f;do printf "\e]1337;File=inline=1:$(if [[ $f = *://* ]];then curl -Ls "$f";else cat -- "$f";fi|base64)\a\n";done;}
```

To display images at a maximum height of 20 rows, add `;height=20`.